# 400 bad request after url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am getting a 400 Bad request whenever i go to a product page - www.link.com/product/123/foo

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$ product.php?product_id=$1&product_name=$2 [B,NC,L]
```

Comment: Why are there tags for `php` and `mysql`?